# How can a subdomain for a minecraft server hide the port number?

Tags: port, minecraft, cname

I've rented a Minecraft server, and the server has a shared IP address, so the Minecraft server isn't running on the default port. However, the hosting company offers you a subdomain for the server, and when you use it, you don't need to specify the port. But how can this work? Does the Minecraft client report the domain name you entered to the server, and then the server use it to forward the connection to the correct port?

I tried an experiment: under one of my own domains, I set up a CNAME record that directs to the hosting company's subdomain. I found that I have to specify the port to connect.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft checks if there is an [SRV record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) for `_minecraft._tcp.subdomain.domain.tld`. If there is one, it uses the port specified in it.